# AWS SAM - Multi level circular dependency between SAM's lambda and api resources

Tags: aws-cloudformation, swagger-2.0, aws-sam

I am building a large application that has "static" resources (API, lambda LayerVersions, DynamoDB table etc) and "dynamic" resources (Lambda functions, Batch and SQS queues).

To neatly arrange this, I created multiple template files with some referring to others using SAM's `AWS::Serverless::Application` type.

In some of the "modules" (1 level deep nested stacks) I have lambdas that act as lambda proxies, and the API that they integrate with is declared in the `StaticResourcesModule` nested stack.

However these lambda need `AWS::Serverless::Api`'s `RestApiId` property [to know to which event to respond to](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api).

The circular dependency happens because the Swagger 2.0 template that defines the `AWS::Serverless::Api` in the first place [needs the Lambda's ARN (or lambda function's name and account number)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44702589/5989906) to know which lambda implement what method (`x-amazon-apigateway-integration` 's `uri` attribute)

**How can I pass to the API a reference to the lambda when the lambda themselves need a reference to the API's `RestApiId` property and both are in different stacks ?**

The top level YAML template file looks like this:

```
Resources:
  StaticResourcesModule:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: static_resources_module/template.yaml

  DataFetchingModule:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: datafetching_module/template.yaml
      Parameters:
        MainApiId: !GetAtt StaticResourcesModule.Outputs.MainApiId
```

`datafetching_module/template.yaml` :

```
Parameters:
  MainApiId:
    Type: String
    Description: >
      Reference to the main api (AWS::Serverless::Api) resource.

Resources:
  FetchingRequestsHandler:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Description: Handles incoming requests [...]
    Properties:
      [...]
      Events:
        ApiPostNewRequestEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: post
            Path: /fetching/low-priority
            RestApiId: !Ref MainApiId
```

`static_resources_module/template.yaml`:

```
Parameters:
    FetchingRequestsHandlerArn:
        Type: String
Resources:
  MainApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      DefinitionUri: api/swagger2_template.yaml

Outputs:
 MainApiId:
   Value: !Ref MainApi
   Description: The Main API's RestApiId which to provide to the Lambda that require an API Event (lambda proxy)
```

`api/swagger2_template.yaml`:

```
  /fetching/low-priority:
    post:
      # API integration, necessary.
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${FetchingRequestsHandlerArn}/invocations"
```